# Estimated Users and total number of users mismatch in AWS cognito userpool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an issue while copying the users from one user pool to another user pool Total users are 10 but the estimated users are showing 9 and the total users are showing 10 what will be the issue for this why the estimated user count is 9 instead of 10?

What will be the reason for the users count mismatch like estimated users and total number of users